# Is 訴え連日通い a single word? If not, why no particles in between?

Tags: translation, words, adverbs

I'm reading **`イン.　ザ.　プール`**, where I found the following clause in one of its lines:

> 身体の不調を**訴え連日通いつめる**和雄

I roughly translated it to **"Kazuo who strictly complains about his bad health on a daily basis."**

What I don't understand is 「**訴え連日通いつめる**」

> **1:** I feel like there are 3 words here and not just 1: 訴え、連日、通い, if that's the case, why there is no particles in between them?
>
> **2:** If I understand correctly, **つめる is modifying 身体の不調**, but if that is the case, what is the function of **訴え連日通い** here? Is it working like an adverb and modifying **つめる**?

Comment: Try parsing this as 訴え連日 and 通いつめる instead, since I believe it's a compound verb composed of 通う and 詰める

Comment: @psosuna you're right, https://jisho.org/word/%E9%80%9A%E3%81%84%E3%81%A4%E3%82%81%E3%82%8B, the lack of comma after 訴え was the thing that made me confuse it all. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can parse it as...

> ｛身体の不調を訴え｝｛連日通いつめる｝和雄

和雄 does two actions: 体の不調を訴える "complains about health problem / says he doesn't feel well" and 連日通いつめる "visits (somewhere) on consecutive days / every day".

訴え here is the continuative form (連用形) of the verb 訴える. 連用形 can connect verb phrases or clauses, like the て form.
The phrase can be rephrased as 「身体の不調を訴え**て**、連日～～」, using the て form.

連日 is a noun, and can function adverbially, like 毎日, 今日, 来年 etc.
eg 「**毎日**、学校に通っています。」「**連日**働きづめです。」

通いつめる, "pay frequent visits", is a compound verb consisting of 通う (visit) + 詰める (do ~~ continuously, frequently, completely, thoroughly, etc.)

Comment: I believe the lack of comma was throwing me off, if it was 身体の不調を訴え、連日通いつめる和雄 I would have no problem. Is it common to have continuative forms without comma after that? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @FelipeOliveira そうですね、 yes, I think it's pretty common. I think it's more common in formal writing... たぶん。